# jquery var and $(var).css

Tags: jquery, css, dom, var

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fa-crosshairs').click(function() {
    $('*').click(function() {
      var currentclass = $(this).attr('class');
    });
  });
  $('#1color').click(function() {
    $('body').css({
      "background-color": "black"
    });
  });
});
```

I need to get currentclass var, then use it instead of $('body').css, but i dont know how i have to do it.

The point is to get one element by clicking, and then, change its css when i click on ('#1color')

Comment: What is this $('*').click(function() { you are binding all the element  inside of fa-crosshairs click event

Comment: Show ur DOM structure or make a fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the variable globally.

Here's an example of how you could do this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elem;
  $('.fa-crosshairs').click(function() {
    elem = this;
  });
  $('input').click(function() {
    $( elem).css({
      "background-color": "teal",
      "color": "white"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fa-crosshairs">One</div>
<div class="fa-crosshairs">Two</div>
<div class="fa-crosshairs">Three</div>
<div class="fa-crosshairs">Four</div>
<div class="fa-crosshairs">Five</div>
<div class="fa-crosshairs">Six</div>
<input type="button" value="Change" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable 
`var currentclass = $(this).attr('class');` is declared inside a function. so that it is accessible inside the function where it is declared. The scope of the variable is inside that function. You need to declare the variable as **GLOBAL VARIABLE** so that it is accessible outside the function.
[SCOPE OF A VARIABLE](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)